# How native is the iOS shared module of Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile?

Tags: ios, swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

How is the shared module of Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile realized on the iOS platform? Is it transpiled to Swift code or how does that work? How performant is it compared to Swift code?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but my guess would be the framework you add to iOS project to access "common" code is just a VM running Kotlin code. I really doubt it would transpile Kotlin code to Swift code - that would be too much work to make that work in all cases.
As for performance... Of course, you have one more framework in the memory, so the app will be heavier. How heavier - guess that depends on what code you share and so on.

Comment: there's no VM, kotlin code is translated into native C++ and ObjC headers are generated to provide usability from swift. performance is good unless you do something wrong. better read articles from adopters for more details, I don't think such a question is appropriate for SO

Comment: As stated, no VM. Kotlin is compiled using llvm and friends to architecture binary, similar to what happens with Swift. The interface is Objc, but it's not an Objc or Swift transpiler. There will be direct Swift interop at some point, but the timeline is TBD. Performance varies, but that's true of all platforms. Depends what you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Kotlin/Native is a technology for compiling Kotlin code to native binaries which can run without a virtual machine. Kotlin/Native includes an [LLVM](https://llvm.org/)-based backend for the Kotlin compiler and a native implementation of the Kotlin standard library."

When you compile kotlin for iOS, it uses the standard iOS library via bindings, so the performance here is completely native. If, for example, not just syscalls are performed but some calculations: kotlin native is compiled using llvm(not [transpiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler) to swift), as well as swift, which means that the same optimizations will be involved. Also, when interacting with ObjC/Swift, kotlin creates wrappers for its objects containing reference counters (the same as in the ObjC/Swift ARC runtime) which also contributes to a more native interaction.

So yea, it can be faster or slower in some cases, but it's pretty native.